# Apply scale to armature works on rest position but breaks poses

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, keyframes, scale

I have an animated model (link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9ked8yl2opl2or/robotERS_channelcleaning.blend?dl=0) that I am trying to rescale. Right now the armature and the mesh are not parented (yet).

The armature is scaled (object mode) to 0.01 on all axes. I want this size to be the new 1.0 scale.
If I apply the scale to the armature, the rest pose looks good, but all animations are broken afterwards and I cannot find out why.

Any help is hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A script to do this.**

[image]
*Result of running script, idle action, note unit scale*

**Method**

For each action select and remove the location fcurves,

[image]
*via UI select all pose bones, search for "location" select and delete*

Alternatively scale the location keyframes. *In this case after applying scale to rig any translation fcurve would be 100x more than need be, this was the visible problem moving hips and spine apart a hundredfold*  As mentioned only rotation keyframes are needed for any bone with a parent.

for all pose bones set location to 0, 0, 0 if not already  Select all pose bones, Set active pose bone location to all zero, right click copy all to selected will set all pose bones back to zero.

Then apply the scale.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> scale.

Here is a script to do this.  As with all scripts, backup first. Script rundown.

- For a parent hierarchy of bones and in place animation will find location
  keyframes are not required.  First part of script removes all
  location keyframes.
- Any residual pose bone locations are reset to zero.  *All zero
  location and rotation is the rest pose.*
- Finally the scale is applied to your rig.

Select the rig object in object mode, and run script.

```
import bpy
for a in bpy.data.actions:
    for fc in a.fcurves:
        if "location" in fc.data_path:
            a.fcurves.remove(fc)

ob = bpy.context.object
for pb in ob.pose.bones:
    pb.location = (0, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
```

Finally you have rotation keyframes on the rig object, which also appear unnecessary.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!! Is there no way to do it without scripting?

Comment: so what was the problem? How would you do it without script? Thanks in advance